# Is it good or bad style declaring an overridden method with 'virtual' and 'override' keywords?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overriding

Imagine having the following classes:

```
class A {
    virtual void foo();
};

class B : public A {
    virtual void foo() override;
};
```

I know that using 'override' prevents broken polymorphism. But is it good style to still add the 'virtual' keyword to the derived method?

Comment: Good question, this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443353/how-to-override-virtual-function-in-good-style-c Largely down to personal choice. I don't repeat.

Comment: It depends on what do you expect when remove `virtual` keyword from the base class member function.

Comment: But does having `virtual` in a child class `virtual`-ise the base class where `virtual` is missing?

Comment: @Bathsheba.. i don't think `virtual`-sation gets propagated upwards.

Comment: @SauravSahu: That makes two of us: my question was a rhetorical one.

Comment: I always use virtual, because it makes the prototype of the function look (nearly) the same in all places, with 'override' becoming single extension in children.

Comment: Related, w.r.t. `override` keyword: [Implementing pure virtual function from abstract base class: does override specifier have any meaning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39370403).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is it good style to still add the 'virtual' keyword to the derived method?

In your case, `virtual` keyword is implicit in derived class methods as it is *propagated down implicitly* from `class A` to `class B`.

Compilers may complain through warning if 'virtual' keyword is not mentioned explicitly.

Pros: Gives clear indication of being `virtual`, especially useful in deep class hierarchies.

Cons: Not cleaner or clearer look.

Comment: You are ignoring the fact that `override` can only be applied to virtual functions.

Comment: Yes that is true. Derived class method is anyway implicitly virtual. So we can directly append `override` keyword in its declaration.

Comment: So to keep compilers quit AND prevent broken polymorphism, I think the best choice is to use both keywords simultaniously